# Passenger fails to send whole request to RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Recently, we are facing a strange problem where some XHR requests, sent from Passenger to our application server, fail to execute properly.

Please have look at following chain of events:

1. LB Passenger sends a request to the application server.
2. Rails returns a NoMethodError exception when trying to figure out which controller action this request is supposed to be processed by.

   ```
   Rails error log:


   Started POST "/user/" for 194.29.65.21 at 2013-03-25 13:14:38 +0100
     NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
   ```

   Here is a log when Rails is able to figure out which controller/action a request should be routed to:

   ```
   Started POST "/User/" for 194.29.65.21 at 2013-03-25 13:14:38 +0100
        Processing by Web::UserController#index as 
        Parameters: {"c"=>"1", "fref"=>""}
   ```
3. This error gets propagated to the application server passenger which throws the following error:

   ```
   [ pid=20071 thr=3074915216 file=ext/nginx/HelperAgent.cpp:577
   time=2013-03-24 22:25:58.257 ]: Uncaught exception in PassengerServer
   client thread:    exception: Cannot read response from backend
   process: Connection reset by peer (104)    backtrace:
        in 'void Client::forwardResponse(Passenger::SessionPtr&, Passenger::FileDescriptor&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:361)
        in 'void Client::handleRequest(Passenger::FileDescriptor&)' (HelperAgent.cpp:503)
        in 'void Client::threadMain()' (HelperAgent.cpp:596)
   ```
4. And finally LB Nginx gives this error:  `up stream status = 500 error`.

This error comes randomly for a given route. Even the frequency of occurrence of this error changes randomly.

System details:

- Ruby: 1.9.2p180
- Rails : 3.0.5
- Phusion Passenger version 3.0.5
- nginx version: n

We think this happens because Passenger is failing to send the whole request data to Rails which results in Rails failing to decide the valid controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Review passenger config for nginx, I have experienced a lot issues with passenger for nginx.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerSpawnMethod specially verify this configuration and and add this in nginx.conf in parent node.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I just checked my config and I have not explicitly  set passenger_spawn_method; so it is set to smart. Wondering what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We just debugged and found that issue is not with XHR but with POST requests.

Also right now we are using passenger 3.0.5, does any know if upgrading to passenger 3.0.19 help?